# Adding drag and drop to mat-chip list within mat-form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to combine [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v9-mat-select-with-mat-chip-list?file=package.json) (A dropdown selection that creates mat-chips of selected values) with a drag and drop functionality borrowed from Angular Material's [Mat-Chip examples](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples) (second example from the top) but for some reason the drag and drop doesn't work. I can drag a chip and when hovering it over another chip it seems to change index but when I drop it (release mouse button) it goes back to it's original place. Is this a compatibility issue with the Material components? This is my code currently:

HTML:

```
  <mat-form-field class="field">
  <mat-label>Choose values</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppingsControl" multiple>
    <mat-select-trigger>
      <mat-chip-list
        cdkDropList
        cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
      >
        <mat-chip
          cdkDrag
          *ngFor="let topping of toppingsControl.value"
          [removable]="true"
          (removed)="onToppingRemoved(topping)"
        >
          {{ topping.name }}
          <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
      </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-select-trigger>

    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppings" [value]="topping">{{
      topping.name
    }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Typescript:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from "@angular/cdk/drag-drop";

export interface Topping {
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-control',
  templateUrl: 'control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['control.component.scss'],
})
export class ControlComponent {
  toppingsControl = new FormControl([]);
  toppings: Topping[] = [
    {name: 'Value_0'},
    {name: 'Value_1'},
    {name: 'Value_2'},
    {name: 'Value_3'},
    {name: 'Value_4'}
  ];

  onToppingRemoved(topping: string) {
    const toppings = this.toppingsControl.value as string[];
    this.removeFirst(toppings, topping);
    this.toppingsControl.setValue(toppings); // To trigger change detection
  }

  private removeFirst<T>(array: T[], toRemove: T): void {
    const index = array.indexOf(toRemove);
    if (index !== -1) {
      array.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Topping[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.toppings, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);

}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your example, saw one mistake

Mistake 1:  When you are dragging(here `drop` function) the Chips only changes occurs in the array parameter but not the formcontroller parameter. If you change the position of controllers then you will get whats required. ie,

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Topping[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.toppings, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);

}}
```

becomes

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Topping[]>) {     
    moveItemInArray(this.toppings, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    moveItemInArray(this.toppingsControl.value, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
```

Hope this will clear your doubts. For further reference go through `multi-test` of the below example. Here you can do the comparison with the original examples(that you provided).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v9-mat-select-with-mat-chip-list-lcwahb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmulti-test-example.ts

Comment: This is correct, thank you!